# What is the <views:...> command in Xaml and how do I use it/find reference for it?

Tags: xaml

Trying to implement the nifty animation solution described here: https://www.kymphillpotts.com/simple-animation-with-xamarin-forms/

But when I cut and paste this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage x:Class="Animation.AnimationPage" xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Animation" xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Animation.Views" 
BackgroundColor="#181818">
<Grid Padding="0" ColumnSpacing="0" RowSpacing="0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="AUTO" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Image x:Name="MainImage" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Aspect="AspectFill" Source="mugello.jpg">
        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1" Tapped="Handle_Tapped" />
        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
    </Image>

    <views:ExpandBar x:Name="ExpandBar" Grid.Row="1" Padding="0" TranslationY="1" VerticalOptions="End" />

    <views:DescriptionPane x:Name="BottomFrame" Grid.Row="1" IsVisible="true" Text="The Mugello is a historic region and valley in northern Tuscany, in Italy. It is located to the north of the city of Florence and consists of the northernmost portion of the Metropolitan City of Florence.  It is connected to the separate Santerno river valley by the Futa Pass." VerticalOptions="End" />

    <views:Title x:Name="Title" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,40,0,0" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Start" />
</Grid>
```

I end up with a lot of errors around the `<views:...>` code, saying “missing an assembly reference?”

This is a particularly hard thing to search Google for, because when you search `<views:...`,  even if you include the quotation marks, google just discard the punctuation and you end up simply getting tons of pages on MVVM.

It would be awesome if somebody could tell me how to use this command, and probably even better, how to find documentation on it!

Comment: It's a namespace reference.  Learn about XAML namespace and check for `xmlns:views="..."`

Comment: Okay but that namespace stuff isnt in the code itself. Are you sure that’s what’s happening? Is it common to post code like this and not the namespace definitions? I really don’t know if you’re right about this. When I search for namespaces I find lots of stuff on using “x:” definitions but that’s not what I’m asking about, I’m asking about the “views:” statements.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/xaml-namespaces-and-namespace-mapping-for-wpf-xaml#mapping-to-custom-classes-and-assemblies

Comment: Ok, I see where you think that the link references my problem, and I see how my question might make it seem like the only problem here is namespaces, but that's not really it. It's much simpler and probably much more of a noob issue. All it is is the creation and referencing of `ContentViews` in separate files. I've explained more in my own answer.

Comment: I upvoted your comments though because I appreciate you trying to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it's *partially* a namespace thing, but that's not the whole story, and for the sake of anyone else encountering this confusion, here's the whole answer.

First off, yes, the namespace thing is how the word `views` gets in there, and it's in this line at the start of the file:

```
xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Animation.Views"
```

...the word `views` there can be anything, btw, as long as you use it consistently in the rest of the commands on the same page. This basically just points to the path where the view definitions are.

And that's the other part of this, that for this to work, there must be other Xaml files somewhere with `ContentView` definitions. And the part of the namespace definition that comes after `clr-namespace:` has to *indicate the namespace declared at the head of the codebehind for those other Xaml files*.

And, crucially, those other files are *not* shown on the blog post that the original code comes from.

It's possible that part is totally obvious to people with more experience. But it wasn't to me.

So for a complete example here's a Xaml file that would define a view called `ContentDingle`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView
    xmlns ="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="MyApp.ContentDingle">
    <Grid ColumnSpacing="0" RowSpacing="0">
        <Label 
            Text="I can now be referenced with the views command!"
            VerticalOptions="Center" />
    </Grid>
</ContentView>
```

...and the only change necessary to the code-behind is to change the superview to `ContentView` instead of `ContentPage`.

And then here's how you can reference it in a different Xaml file, with no modification necessary to the codebehind:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage
    x:Class        ="MyApp.ContactDingleShowingPage"
    xmlns         ="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x        ="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:views    ="clr-namespace:MyApp"
    BackgroundColor="#181818">
    <Grid>
        <views:ContentDingle/>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

The part of this that all the other answers were missing is the explanation of the separate files, and how they should be declared, and how to reference them. This is probably noob stuff, again, but hopefully it's of help to other noobs out there.

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't get those errors only if you replace your above code with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage x:Class="Animation.AnimationPage" xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Animation" xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Animation.Views" BackgroundColor="#181818">

<Grid Padding="0" ColumnSpacing="0" RowSpacing="0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="AUTO" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Image x:Name="MainImage" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Aspect="AspectFill" Source="mugello.jpg">
        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1" Tapped="Handle_Tapped" />
        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
    </Image>

    <views:ExpandBar x:Name="ExpandBar" Grid.Row="1" Padding="0" TranslationY="1" VerticalOptions="End" />

    <views:DescriptionPane x:Name="BottomFrame" Grid.Row="1" IsVisible="true" Text="The Mugello is a historic region and valley in northern Tuscany, in Italy. It is located to the north of the city of Florence and consists of the northernmost portion of the Metropolitan City of Florence.  It is connected to the separate Santerno river valley by the Futa Pass." VerticalOptions="End" />

    <views:Title x:Name="Title" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,40,0,0" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Start" />
</Grid>
```

This is the code I found from the link you provided, surely there is a `Contentpage` and it has the namespace defined in it. I don't know why you did not find it.

as others have already told you, `view` here is a namespace. Learn what a namespace is from [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/xaml-namespaces-and-namespace-mapping-for-wpf-xaml)

Comment: I don't know why that top part didn't show up when I pasted it, but it is actually already in the files where I'm getting errors. Namespaces weren't really the issue, though I see why everybody thought it was. I'm going to edit my original post to reflect the missing code, just so people don't get confused. I upvoted you because I appreciate your trying to help.